# Is string offset an alias for substring? Do string offsets dynamically allocate memory?

Tags: php, internals

Take these two lines as an example.

```
ord($str[0])
ord(substr($str, 0, 1))
```

I'm aware that the second line would dynamically allocate heap memory, copy the first character into a new string, and pass that to `ord`. Does the first line do the same? Or does it just load the byte at that offset and pass it by value to `ord`?

Comment: If there's an optimization, it could be done in both cases. `ord()` only cares about the first character.

Comment: The [VLD output here](https://3v4l.org/00cig/vld#output) might be useful

Comment: And for the difference https://3v4l.org/AGDgM/vld#output vs. https://3v4l.org/g7tb0/vld#output